# WordPress Customer Review plugin, reviews not saving

Tags: php, wordpress

I have posted this on the plugin support forum but thought I would post here too.

I'm using the shortcode `[WPCR_INSERT]` on a number of pages and am having varied results.

The form to write a review shows up on all pages where the shortcode is used, however, on the homepage the review will not save. Indeed, I don't receive the "thank you" message so it doesn't appear to be posting correctly.

The shortcode works fine on normal posts and pages, just not on the themes "front" page.

The theme is called "appply" and you can view a copy of the problem website here: `http://cableconnecting.jdfx.co.uk/`

I've been bashing my head against a wall for hours with this one any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Joel

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/
```

Answer (score 0):

A comment in the [source code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-customer-reviews/trunk/wp-customer-reviews.php) of the plugin states "we can only use the plugin if we have a valid post ID". An additional check makes sure the plugin is only usable on single post pages. This is the relevant code:

```
if ( !isset($post) || !isset($post->ID) || intval($post->ID) == 0 ) {
    return false; /* we can only use the plugin if we have a valid post ID */
}

if (!is_singular()) {
    return false; /* not on a single post/page view */
}
```

Comment: Thanks diggy, that makes sense. Can you think of a way i could force (hack) the plugin to use a fall-back post-id in the event that it's used on a non-post page. In my case it doesn't actually matter which ID the review is stored against.

Comment: I think you get a post ID and meet the `is_singular()` condition when you explicitly set a page as front page in general settings -> reading.